# Display and parse images from DB to listview

Tags: android, mysql, android-listview, uri, adapter

I have to display data from mysql database in the listview of my android app. I have successfully parsed the textual data and displayed it in custom listview but the image are not being parsed and displayed in the list. I have tried using imageloader, file cache, memory cache, but still have not succeeded.

If anyone have any idea about what is missing or what should be added to it, any help would be appreciated.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView tourname;
    TextView duration;
    ImageView flag;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row1, parent, false);
 // Get the position from the results


 // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
    tourname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.themeTourList_title); 
    duration = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.themeTourList_price);  
    // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
    flag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.themeTourList_image); 

    // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
    try
    {
        tourname.setText(mJSONArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("tour_name"));
        duration.setText(""+mJSONArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("nights")+" Nights - "+mJSONArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("days")+" Days");
        try{
        URL url = new URL("www.futurolicht.com/"+mJSONArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("pic"));
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)(url).getContent());
        flag.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below method to Download Images:

```
URL url = new URL(src);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```